# How can I know which nodes in a cluster are actual master nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I use ES 2.2.0. and have a cluster of nodes. I would like to know which node or nodes are actual master ones. How can I do that?

I tried the following ways:

```
curl http://my_computer:9200/_cluster/state?pretty
curl http://my_computer:9200/_nodes?pretty
```

and I was unable to find which node is master.

Comment: Do you mean which node is the master node or which nodes are master-eligible nodes? Or are you simply requesting about primary **shards** (see below answer)?

Comment: Val, you are right. I meant which nodes in a cluster are actual master ones, not just master-eligible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is only ever one single master in a cluster, chosen among the set of master-eligible nodes.

You can either run the [`/_cat/master`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-master.html) command or the [`/_cat/nodes`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html) command.

The former will yield something like this

```
% curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/master?v'
id                     ip            node
Ntgn2DcuTjGuXlhKDUD4vA 192.168.56.30 Solarr
```

and the latter command will yield the list of nodes with the `master` column (`m` for short). Nodes with `m` are master-eligible nodes and the one with the `*` is the current master.

```
% curl 192.168.56.10:9200/_cat/nodes?v&h=id,ip,port,v,m
id   ip            port version m
pLSN 192.168.56.30 9300 2.2.0   m
k0zy 192.168.56.10 9300 2.2.0   m
6Tyi 192.168.56.20 9300 2.2.0   *
```

Answer (score 2):

With respect to ***Elasticsearch 6.6***, this is how you can get the id of the `master_node`

> `curl -X GET "192.168.0.1:9200/_cluster/state/master_node?pretty"`

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "logbox",
  "compressed_size_in_bytes" : 11150,
  "cluster_uuid" : "eSpyTgXbTJirTjWtPW_HYQ",
  "master_node" : "R8Gn9Km0T92H9D7TXGpX4k"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't nodes that are primary, but shards.  If you check out https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/cat-shards.html

You can try something like: http://my_computer:9200/_cat/shards?v

Comment: sinneduy, thanks so much for your input. I had a typo in the original question.  I meant which nodes in a cluster are actual master ones, not just master-eligible